# Q notation does not work with variable in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

the variable `var_chassis` has a below value:

```
var_chassis =554789-9887-2222,5669-221-007
```

I want to add single quotes around this and expected output is below (new_var_chassis is a new variable here)

```
new_var_chassis='554789-9887-2222,5669-221-007'
```

tried doing this using q quotes however its not working with variable? is there a regex to do this

```
 select q'['var_chassis']' from dual;
```

Comment: You rather need to concatenate single-quotes to your variable, something like this: `q'[']' || new_var_chassis || q'[']'`. Why are you doing this though? Note that you won't be able to use the resulting string in an `IN` condition in SQL anyway (for reasons that should be, but sometimes don't seem to be, obvious to any competent SQL programmer).

Comment: Wonderful!!!!! works like charm. You made it more simpler and Its just for representation. sorry Not able to vote this for low credits